# Binary algorithm for finding the range of elements

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering, binary, searching

Consider a sorted list of real numbers `listz` and some boolean condition `condition` that involves these numbers:

```
listz = Table[z, {z, 480., 515., 0.2}];
condition[z_(*,hidden variables_*)] = Boole[500 <= z <= 505(*&& condition on hidden variables*)];
```

I need to find the minimal and maximal positions of the elements of `listz` for which `cond` returns 1. I cannot use obvious operations like `Position[listz, Select[listz, # >= 500 &] // Min]`. The reason is that, in my real case, I do not have 1-to-1 correspondence between `condition` and `z`: it depends not only on `z` but also on some hidden variables; so, e.g. for some variables, the range may be narrower than the direct z-selection. I cannot simply compute the list of values of `condition`: it is very expensive. The only general feature I know is that the domain from `listz` for which `condition` returns 1 is connected: the list of `condition` values is always `{0,...,0,1,...,1,0,...0}`.

Because of this, I considered using binary search for this purpose. However, the code I made for this does not work:

```
lowest = 
 Hold@Compile[{{listz, _Real, 1}}, 
     Module[{low = 1, high = Length[listz], mid = 0, val = 0.},
      While[low < high,
       mid = Floor[(low + high)/2] // IntegerPart;
       val = condition[Compile`GetElement[listz, mid]];
       If[val == 1, high = mid, low = mid + 1];
       ];
      low
      ], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
     RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}] /. DownValues@condition // 
  ReleaseHold
```

This is because the desired range is in the 2nd half of `listz`, and my algorithm immediately goes to the wrong domain. I may manually correct it to return to the 2nd half if  I would never get the unit value of `condition`. However, then, the range may be in the 2nd half of the 2nd half, and so on. Moreover, `listz` may be defined in a way such that the desired range is in the 1st half - I do not know this a priori.

Is there a proper binary algorithm allowing us to find the desired range? If not, what could be an efficient alternative?

**Edit**

It looks like the binary algorithm may be efficiently applied here only if I know the position of one element within the range where `condition` returns 1. Otherwise, I would need to iterate...

Comment: There is a [binary search](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Combinatorica/ref/BinarySearch.html) included in the combinatorica package. Also, there is a [BinarySearchBy](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/BinarySearchBy) function in the function repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a recursive binary search to find one position that fulfills the condition. From this you may make a binary search downwards and upwards to get the first and last position that fulfills the condition:

```
step[low_, high_] := Module[{pos},
   If[high - low < 2, Return[Nothing[]]]; 
   If[condition[listz[[pos = low + Round[(high - low)/2]]]] == 1, 
    Return[pos], {step[low, pos], step[pos, high]} // Flatten]
   ];
len = Length[listz];
posmin = posmax = step[1, len];
While[(tmp = step[1, posmin[[1]]]) != {}, posmin = tmp];
While[(tmp = step[posmax[[1]], len]) != {}, posmax = tmp];
{posmin[[1]], posmax[[1]]}

{101, 126}
```

However, note that you can use "Position" and "FirstPositio"n even if your condition does not return "1". E.g.:

```
FirstPosition[listz, x_ /; condition[x] == 1]

{101}
```